# Help with a proof involving Galois theory and fixed fields

Tags: group-theory, permutations, galois-theory

I'm trying to prove the following:

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$. Let $L/k$ be a Galois extension with Galois group $G$. Let $H\subset G$ be a subgroup. Show that there exists an element $\alpha$ in $L$ whose stabiliser under the action of the Galois group $G$ on $L$ is $H$.

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$ It appears that one needs to use the fixed field of $H$ to show that such an $\alpha$ exists. Let $\alpha\in L$, then it follows that the

$$\textbf{Fix}(H) = \{\alpha\in L\;|\; \phi(\alpha)=\alpha, \; \forall \phi\in H\}  .$$

We know that $\textbf{Fix}(H)$ is a subfield of $L$.  I'm a bit lost on how to proceed with the part which states that "..under the action of the Galois group $G$ on $L$ is $H$".

Comment: Since $H$ is a finite subgroup of $Aut(L)$, with $L^H = \{ a \in L, \forall \phi \in H, \phi(a) = a\}$ then $L/L^H$ is a Galois extension with Galois group $H$, and since $L/k$ is a finite separable extension then so is $L^H/k$ and you want a [primitive element](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~greenber/MATH404-PrimElem.pdf) $\alpha$ ie. $L^H = k(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 0):

What you need for this problem are

- [Primitive element theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem)
- [Fundamental theorem of Galois theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory), or specifically, the Galois correspondence.

Since the extension $L/k$ is finite and separable, so is $L^H/k$ (here I write $L^H$ for $\mathbf{Fix}(H)$). By the Primitive element theorem, there is an element $\alpha\in L^H$ such that $L^H=k(\alpha)$, as reuns has pointed out. The Galois correspondence says that the correspondences $E\mapsto \mathrm{Gal}(L/E)$ and $H\mapsto L^H$ are bijective, where $E$ is an intermediate field of $L/k$ and $H\leqslant G$. Since $L^H=k(\alpha)=L^{\mathrm{Stab}(\alpha)}$, then the Galois correspondence implies that $\mathrm{Stab}(\alpha)=H$.